# How to set object name in request body for json parsing in Ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization

I am new in JSON parsing, I am using following code to post data to server

```
    NSDictionary *newDatasetInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:ClassicLevel, @"ClassicLevel",CurrentLevel,@"CurrentLevel",UpdatedDate,@"UpdatedDate",Name,@"Name",UpdatedTime,@"UpdatedTime", nil];

    NSError*error;
    //convert object to data
    NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:newDatasetInfo options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://testURL"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
```

By using this I am able to generate following  request body

```
{
 "Name":"abc",
 "UpdatedDate":"",
 "CurrentLevel":"2",
 "UpdatedTime":"122",
 "ClassicLevel":"1" 
}
```

But I have to generate request body like:

```
{
"objTimesheet" : 
    {
    "Name":"abc",
    "UpdatedDate":"",
    "CurrentLevel":"2",
    "UpdatedTime":"122",
    "ClassicLevel":"1" 
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hello I have to pass same request but with pass the value of username and password in request
Any idea?

Comment: @keyurbhalodiya:Try this..NSDictionary *newDatasetInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:strUsername , @"usernameKey ",strPassword ,@"passwordKey", nil];..Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for a dictionary inside a dictionary.  Going off what you already have:

```
NSDictionary *newDatasetInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:ClassicLevel, @"ClassicLevel",CurrentLevel,@"CurrentLevel",UpdatedDate,@"UpdatedDate",Name,@"Name",UpdatedTime,@"UpdatedTime", nil];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:newDatasetInfo, @"objTimesheet", nil];

NSError*error;
//convert object to data
NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```